# Token Pattern for Android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, token

I have an Android project in which I get a token from the server for authentication and use it for further queries to the server. The token expires approximately in 10 minutes so I have to fetch a new one. My current pattern is like that:

**1-** Fetch the token when the user first starts the application

**2-** Block the user input with a "Please Wait" dialog so he does not try to send queries with a null token from other activites

**3-** Save the token and the timestamp, stop blocking user input

**4-** Check the timestamp regularly in `onCreate()` methods of the activities

**5-** Update if necessary.

My problem is this; if user opens an activity and the token is expired my application again blocks the user input and tries to fetch the token. However, in background, normal logic/flow of the application continues and it tries to send a query to the server with an old or a null token.

So I want to block this query task -which is an `AsyncTask` like the token fetching- and start it after the token fetching is finished. How can i use this pattern and is this a correct one?

**Making one thread wait for another to finish?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using the Android Account manager with a custom authenticator for handling the tokens. The [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) shows you how to proceed with that. Use the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)'s getAuthToken to fetch the current token. In the authenticator you can include logic to invalidate tokens at timeout which will cause the authenticator at the next request for a token to contact the server.

But I guess it could be too much overhead for your project to implement this. Two approaches I see for your current setup:

1. Maybe you can try to simply [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) the current query and fire a new one after you have retrieved a new token?
2. Use [Java synchronization primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to block. E.g., create a "lock" object and use it in the async task and where you update your token:

   ```
   protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
       //
       // the request and other stuff that does not require the token.

       synchronized(lock) {
           //
           // communicate with the server.
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you provide a good resource to study on java concurrency possibly with a lot of examples. I have read several times the official Java Tutorial but I still couldn't have a good grasp of it.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I'm using. There are probably some books available on the subject, but I don't know any off the top of my head to recommend to you. You can probably also find some nice slideshows at Slideshare (http://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?searchfrom=header&q=java+concurrency).